# Create top ten list of items in php

Tags: php

I would like to create an app where my users can create their top ten movies assigning values from 1 to 10. Each user will be able to choose from my movies data table. For examle my data contains 100 movies and each user can give values (1 to 10) to 10 of them.

Comment: *if you look up you can see a very common species of programmers: "uncreativos programmerdos". though lack of creativity should be fatal for these species, they simply will not extinct.* creativity is a *must* in programming. think of what you want to achieve, split that in little chunks. this allows you to remain overview over your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, first you must get the movies from the database and list them.

For example, a simple select-query that selects all the movies and shows them to the user using a while-loop.

```
$get_movies = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `movies`");

while($row_movies = mysql_fetch_array($get_movies);)
{
echo $row_movies['title'];
}
```

You then allow the user to rate the movies, using a select-box that you can show on the same row.

Now, when the user selects, say for example 4; you save that value to the database (using javascript to automatically post the form), and reload the page. The next time the list loads, the select-boxes contain every number from 1 - 10, except for 4 since it's already been used. You can also use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) to do this.

Of course, you will need a column in the database that holds the rating of the movie. And also, to make sure that the correct row is selected, you can always create one form per row holding the ID of the movie in a hidden field.

To ensure that the user doesn't cheat your script by de-activating javascript, you can always filter your script using PHP to make sure that there is only one form being sent, and to make sure that the ID actually exists in your database. And also, don't forget to escape the strings used in your mysql queries.